# How I can connect my paypal account with Virtuemart Joomla?

Tags: joomla, paypal, virtuemart

I have developed a shopping cart using virtuemart and added few products. Now I want to integrate my paypal account with my website. Is there any detailed information about how I can link my account with paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VM admin under the Store menu, click the List Payment Methods menu. One of the options should be Paypal. Click Paypal to edit the configuration. You should only need to make the payment option Active and add your Paypal email address to get it working.

If you have a Paypal Payments Pro account, then you will need to get a payment plugin to handle payments pro. To my knowledge, there are no free ones, but the commercial ones are reasonably priced.